# " "のような特殊文字を普通の文字に変換する方法

Tags: java, string

" "のようなフォントを変えたわけでもないのに普通とは異なる表示ができる文字があるようなのですが、これらを普通の"Big LOVE"のように変換する方法は無いでしょうか？
以下のページを見るとかなりの種類あるようなので一般的な（できればJavaの）ライブラリがあるといいのですが。
https://appllio.com/Instagram-special-character

Comment: [数学用英数字記号 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%A8%E8%8B%B1%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7), [Unicode 数学用英数字記号 - CyberLibrarian](https://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ax2s-kmtn/ref/unicode/u1d400.html) という物らしいですね。こんな記事 [   （数学用英数字記号）に変換する器](https://ykst51.blogspot.com/2021/01/blog-post.html), [フォントにモジモジするおはなし](https://qiita.com/edg_aim/items/572bb318b044589a8e1b), [窓辺の小石 第54回 数式は文書の女王にして……](https://www.mapion.co.jp/news/column/cobs2388270-1-all/) が何か参考になるかもしれませんし、無くてもWikipediaに掲載されている表から自分で作れるのでは？

Comment: それと関連の度合いは不明ですが、こんな記事が何かの参考になるかも。[Word2010-2016： 数式・フォント・数学用英数記号のポイント（まとめ）](http://office-qa.com/Word/wd973.htm) ちなみにこの中のこんな内容は意味深なように思えます。`数式エリアの字は数学用英数記号であり、アルファベットではない。`

Comment: なぜそれが必要だと思って質問しているのでしょうか？質問の経緯や目的、あとご自身で調べたことを詳細に記載してください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicodeには [Unicode® Character Name](https://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html) があり
(Javaで) 名前を取得できるなら簡単に変換可能です

以下は Pythonのコード

```py
>>> s = " "
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(s[0])
'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL B'
>>>
>>> list(map(unicodedata.name, s))
['MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL B',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL I',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL G',
 'SPACE',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL L',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL O',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL V',
 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL E']
>>>
>>> ''.join(v[-1] if v.startswith('MATHEMATICAL')else ' 'for v in map(unicodedata.name, s))
'BIG LOVE'
```

---

**(追記)**

また, 正規化というのもあり, 例えば

- 「ごはん」,「パン」をそれぞれ 3文字, 2文字の形式 (一般的な普通の文字列)
- 「こ」+ 濁音で「ご」, 「ハ」+ 半濁音で「パ」… (Combining Character を使用)などの形式

この"修飾された文字"列 を上側の単純な形式にするものです
これを利用し, アルファベットを取り出すことが可能

(Pythonでの例)

```py
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)
'BIG LOVE'
```

(Javaでの例)

```java
import java.text.Normalizer;

// (中略)
System.out.println("NFKC: "+Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKC));
System.out.println("NFKD: "+Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD));

// NFKC: BIG LOVE
// NFKD: BIG LOVE
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。以下のページを見るとNFKCが良くて半角変換なども自動で行ってくれるようですね。ただ"Lᵒᵛᵉᵧₒᵤ"のような文字列は文字種を自動的に判別してoveとyouの間にスペースを入れて欲しいのですがそれはできないようです。 https://towardsdatascience.com/difference-between-nfd-nfc-nfkd-and-nfkc-explained-with-python-code-e2631f96ae6c

Comment: NFKCが良いというより目的に合った正規化形式を選ぶ, ということですね。 / 間にスペース入れるのは「正規化」ではないのでムリ。どちらかというと "camelCase"を分離するのに近い気もします (一応 `unicodedata.name`使った処理でコード書けば可能ではあるけれど)